# Monadic conduit map splits the stream

Tags: haskell, monads, conduit

I'm playing around a bit trying to understand `conduit`. Running

```
runConduit $ yield "abc" .| mapC id .| sinkList
```

gives `["abc"]`, while running

```
runConduit $ yield "abc" .| mapMC id .| sinkList
```

gives `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Why does the monadic version split up the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the types at play here. `mapC` expects a function of type `a -> b`, whereas `mapMC` expects `a -> m b` for some instance of `Monad` `m`. In both cases, you're using `id` as that function, and therefore whatever input you're giving is being treated as `b` in the first example, and `m b` in the second. Since the value you're yielding is of type `[Char]`, this breaks down to:

- The first example being a pure transformation on a list of characters
- The second example being a monadic transformation on a single character, inside the list monad

If you want the second example to behave the same as the first, replace `id` with `pure` (or `return`).